# GenericPrincipal IsInRole returns false for HttpContext.User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a credential method to set user credentials via GenericPrincipal. I am using asp.net MVC

```
    public void SetCredentials(HttpContextBase context, string username, bool createPersistenceCookie)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, createPersistenceCookie);

        IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity,new []{"standart"});

        context.User = principal;
    }
```

I want to check **User.IsInRole("standart")** in controller action,  but it returns false.

> - context.User.IsInRole("standart") //returns false

I want to use **context.User** in my application, but it returns always false.

Comment: Is the context user the same as the CurrentPrincipal?

Comment: The fact that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("standart")` returns true contradicts the headline of your post. I recommend you invesigate whether both Thread.CurrentPrincipal and context.User are the same instance as your `principal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used asp.net membership api before. And now you want to create custom principal in your application.

When you send request to server, server uses a new clean HttpContext. So you lost your old informations. If you want to use old session informations is application, you shuld save your data in server or client side. You can do this two way.

- Client cookie
- Server session

I recommand you to use client cookies. Because data is being stored to client side, so you save server resources.

```
   public void SetCredentials(HttpContextBase context, string username, bool createPersistenceCookie)
    {
        var formsAuthenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            username,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds),
            createPersistenceCookie,
            roles
        );

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formsAuthenticationTicket);
        var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(authCookie);
    }
```

I sended encrypted cookie to client side. And I should check this cookie all incoming request to server application.

And now in **Global.asax** file:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie == null) return;

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, ticket.UserData.Split('|'));

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
```

I hope solve your issue.